# Pass Task as a Parameter in C# get me cannot convert from 'method group' to 'Task'

Tags: c#, winforms

I have this method that create splash screen

```
public static async Task CreateSplashScreen(Task action, Form form, string description)
{
    var splashScreenManager = new SplashScreenManager(form, typeof(WaitForm1), true, true)
    {
        SplashFormStartPosition = SplashFormStartPosition.CenterScreen,
    };
    splashScreenManager.ShowWaitForm();
    splashScreenManager.SetWaitFormDescription(description);
    await action;
    splashScreenManager.CloseWaitForm();
    splashScreenManager.Dispose();
}
```

And here's a method for creating and previewing a report

```
public static async Task CreateBlackProductionProjectReport()
    {
        using RepCharpenteProductionByShiftTime report = new();
        SmartHelpers.AddDateRangeShiftTimeQueryParameter(report.sqlDataSource1.Queries[0].Parameters);
        SmartHelpers.AddDateRangeParameter(report);
        await SmartHelpers.AddShiftTimeParameter(report);
        report.ShowRibbonPreviewDialog();
    }
```

On click of a button I call CreateSplashScreen method like that

```
private async void ShowBlackProductionProjectReport(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
    await CreateSplashScreen(CreateBlackProductionProjectReport,
                                             this, 
                                             ReportDescription);
}
```

I got this error

> cannot convert from 'method group' to 'Task'

I try with Action instead of Task as a parameter

```
public static void CreateSplashScreen(Action action,Form form, string description)
```

but I got

> 'Task CreateBlackProductionProjectReport()' has the wrong return type

**What am I missing and how do I fix it?**

Comment: The error is pretty clear. The parameter expects an actual `Task` instance. You're trying to pass a completely unrelated object. A `Task` isn't a method call or delegate

Comment: BTW `async void` should never be used except for asynchronous event handlers. An `async void` method can't be awaited. Use `async Task` if you want to create an asynchronous method that returns no value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first try almost got it correct, you just missed a pair of parenthesis :

For the following signature :

```cs
public static async Task CreateSplashScreen(Task action, Form form, string description)
```

The call would look like :

```cs
private async void ShowBlackProductionProjectReport(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
    await CreateSplashScreen(CreateBlackProductionProjectReport(),
                                             this, 
                                             ReportDescription);
}
```

Without them you are passing what could be assimilated to a `Func<Task>`